# Difficulty in the calculation of accuracy in an RP-algorithm

Tags: probability

I am studying about RP-algorithm from the book *Algebraic Aspects of Cryptography* by *Neal Koblitz*.

The following example is given in the beginning which is the Probabilistic Primality Test.

[image: primality-test]

I understand the scheme of the algorithm but I am facing difficulty in understanding and deducing the probability that given the number  $N$ passes the Fermat Strong Primality Test *k*-times, $N$ is actually prime.
How are they getting the number $1-4^{-k}$ ?

I tried several times to calculate this but I think I need some guidance in doing this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your question "why is the probability of a composite number successfully passing a single iteration $< 4^{-1}$"?  Or, is it rather "I understand that for a single iteration, but why is the probability for $k$ iterations $< 4^{-k}$?  Why are the probabilities independent?"

Answer (score 1):

If a candidate passes the Miller-Rabin test for one choice of $a$, say $a_0$, then according to the theorem at the start of page 46, its probability of being composite is $\leq 25\% = 1/4$.

If it passes the test for a second choice of $a$, say $a_1$, then by the same theorem, it has a further $\leq 25\% = 1/4$ probability of being composite. Combining the two results, one arrives at a $\leq 1/4 \times 1/4 = 1/4^2$ probability.

In general, for $k$ choices of $a$, the probability is brought down to $\leq 1/4^k = 4^{-k}$. Given that an integer is either composite or prime, then if its probability of being composite is $\leq 4^{-k}$, then the probability of being prime is $> 1 - 4^{-k}$.

Comment: Then why can't I calculate the probability of it being prime in the same way as greater than equal to $(3/4)^k$ ? Why do I have to do it the opposite way?

Comment: This is a basic high-school algebra question. Have you tried picking any $k > 1$ and seeing whether the results match?